Secuencia de escape "\S" no valida en DefaultConnection c#
En mi archivo appsettings escribo mi connectionString pero me indica esto al poner el nombre de servidor

error Secuencia de escape "\S" no valida

"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=Desktop026\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MiBase;Integrated Security=True"
},    

Cuando pego el nombre del servidor me lo agrega automaticamente con dos backslash antes de SQLEXPRESS pero eso me devuelve null en la coneccion

Creo que tienes dos problemas.
El primero es con el contenido del archivo AppSettings.json. En una cadena JSON, debes escapar de cualquier barra invertida con otra barra invertida. De lo contrario, la barra invertida y el siguiente carácter se interpretarán como una secuencia de escape.  Por eso recibiste el error, porque "\S" apareció  como una secuencia de escape a JSON, y "\S" no es una secuencia de escape válida en JSON.
La solución es la escapar con otra barra invertida como:
"ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Server=Desktop026\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MiBase;Integrated Security=True" },

El segundo problema que dices es:

Cuando pego el nombre del servidor me lo agrega automaticamente con
dos backslash antes de SQLEXPRESS pero eso me devuelve null en la
coneccion

No sé por qué sucede esto, pero si el JSON es correcto, tal vez la propia conexión no sea correcto.  ¿Puedes probarla con otro programa?
Si tu programa y el base de datos son en el mismo computadora, puedes probar:
"ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MiBase;Integrated Security=True" },

Pero tienes que recordar que "SQLEXPRESS" es el nombre de la instancia de la base de datos en tu computadora.  No sé cómo lo instalaste ni qué nombre usaste.
